# I can't use C API for MySQL prepared statement

Tags: mysql, c, prepared-statement

I am writing a hello-world level tryout of connecting MySQL with **C**. I followed each step in the MySQL Documentation and it still wont work. It is really frustrating.

I am trying to insert things into the table.

Insert statement:

```
insert into students_tbl values('?', ?, '?', '?');
```

Table structure:

```
| students_tbl | CREATE TABLE `students_tbl` (
  `name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

**C** code:

```
    MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(mysql);
    char *statement = "insert into students_tbl values('?', ?, '?', '?');";
    mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, statement, strlen(statement));
    MYSQL_BIND bind[4];
    memset(bind, 0, sizeof(MYSQL_BIND) * 4);

    bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    bind[0].buffer = (void *) "nana";
    bind[0].buffer_length = 4;
    bind[0].is_null = 0;
    bind[0].length = nullptr;

    int sal = 1234;
    bind[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
    bind[1].buffer = &sal;
    bind[1].buffer_length = sizeof(int);
    bind[1].is_null = 0;
    bind[1].length = nullptr;

    bind[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    bind[2].buffer = (void *) "female";
    bind[2].buffer_length = 5;
    bind[2].is_null = 0;
    bind[2].length = nullptr;

    bind[3].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    bind[3].buffer = (void *) "hahaha@hahaha.com";
    bind[3].buffer_length = 17;
    bind[3].is_null = 0;
    bind[3].length = nullptr;

    mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, bind);
    printf("%s", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
    mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);
    printf("%s", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
```

I tried to print something according to the Documentation, but got nothing at all.

I added this to check if MySQL get the number of ? right:

```
int param_count = mysql_stmt_param_count(stmt);
```

The value of param_count is 0, surprisingly... I don't know why this may happen. I checked the character set of the table and switched it to utf8 and it still won't work...

Please help me get it right.

Comment: Remove the quotes from `'?'`

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to fix. MySQL will handle strings just fine in the VALUES argument of your query so there is no need for the quotes around the question marks. We're dealing with pointers when we create the parameters and the statement so const is best:
`const char* statement = "insert into students_tbl values (?, ?, ?, ?);";`

You also want to type cast where possible so for your buffer at index one, I would still do: `bind[1].buffer = (int*) &sal;` even if it seems redundant.Lastly, let MySQL infer as much as it can from the data that you pass so for example, is_null and length aren't necessary here. Here is a working version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Credentials.h"
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


void Log(string s){
    std::cout << "[main] " + s << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    MYSQL* mysql;
    Credentials creds = Credentials();
    char* server = creds.server;
    char* user = creds.user;
    char* password = creds.password;
    char* database = creds.database;

mysql = mysql_init(NULL);

if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql));
}

MYSQL_STMT* stmt;
stmt = mysql_stmt_init(mysql);
const char* statement = "insert into students_tbl values (?, ?, ?, ?);";

printf("%s", "\npreparing...");
if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, statement, strlen(statement))) {
    mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
    mysql_close(mysql);
    Log("Error on prepare");
    Log(mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
}

MYSQL_BIND bind[4];
memset(bind, 0, sizeof(bind)); //<-- simplify this

bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[0].buffer = (char*) "nana"; //<-- char* cast
bind[0].buffer_length = strlen("nana");

int sal = 1234;
bind[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
bind[1].buffer = (int*) &sal;
bind[1].buffer_length = sizeof(int);

bind[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[2].buffer = (char*) "female";
bind[2].buffer_length = strlen("female"); //<-- fixed length

bind[3].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[3].buffer = (char*) "hahaha@hahaha.com";
bind[3].buffer_length = strlen("hahaha@hahaha.com");

printf("%s", "\nbinding...");
mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, bind);
printf("%s", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));

printf("%s", "\nexecuting query...\n");
mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);
printf("%s", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));

mysql_stmt_close(stmt);

return 0;
```

}